# Wordpress search-loop: How to substring the last 6 digits of the pages in the search loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, string, loops, search

So I want to create some sort of custom search for a friend of mine. He wishes to display the pages (There are over 4000 Pages) in the search with the last 6 digits split up from the rest. So that if the customer search it only searches for the title of the page without the last 6 digits. (Also I'm not that sure where to put the code in the search-loop)

I'm a Java developer, and I was wondering if there is a way in PHP to substring the last 6 digits and also create a new string with them, as well as let WordPress only use the shorted string for searching.

Thank you so much!

*Here is an example:

Users search input: US98 2131 4231

WordPress Page-title: US98 2131 4231 543565

WordPress Page-title in the loop: US98 2131 4231*

This should be displayed by the WordPress search:
US98 2131 4231 OUR ID:543565

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = substr("US98 2131 4231 543565", -6, 6);
```

returns $str = "543565". Hope this is the answer your looking for?

Comment: not really. I was looking to doing this with the whole 4000 Pages not only one string